# Istio: How to do canary deployment

Tags: url-routing, istio, traffic, istio-gateway, canary-deployment

Currently there are 3 possible values which we can receive in the header like A1, A2 and A3, and we have three different services running for each value like Service-A1, Service-A2 and Service-A3.

Right now routing is done based on the header value. If value in the header is A1, then it will go to Service-A1, if value in the header is A2 then it will go to Service-A2, and accordingly for A3.

Now, we have new service Service-MultiSupport which can work for all these three values. Now, we want to deploy this new service using canary deployment such that 20% of traffic should go to Service-MultiSupport, and rest of the 80% traffic should work as it is working currently which is header based.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this canary deployment using Istio? I am new to Istio, I tried searching online but couldn't find the proper answer.

Please help if you can.

Thanks in advance.